# Find each img src in document body

Tags: jquery

I want to find each image on a page and replace it with another image

I was attempting this with the following piece of jQuery.

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://myurl.com/mypic.jpg");
}
```

However it is not updating any of the images on the page?  Is there something I have missed?

Comment: Your are missing `background-image: url('../img/share-sprite-new.svg?v=24e64812c790'),none;` for example.

Comment: Because you're missing `)` of `each`

Answer (score 2):

In your code you haven't finished the function with the closing `)`. Try:

```
$("img").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://myurl.com/mypic.jpg");
});
```

Or simplify:

```
$("img").attr("src", "http://myurl.com/mypic.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you're missing ) of `each`.
2. According to the jQuery documentation,:

   > `.attr( attributeName, value )` Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

So no need to use `each`.